# Find the character index from end

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone tell me how to find the character index from the end?

Example:

```
John(Jk)
```

I want to find the `(` from the end.

Result:

```
4
```

Comment: use `charindex()` function  to find the char index as `select charindex('(', 'John(Jk)')`

Comment: What's the expected result for `John(Jk) (1)212`?

Comment: yogesh charindex() which can able to find from first character.

Comment: But my question is to find from last

Comment: @AravindhanR you  could reverse your string and find the char position.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

One way to rephrase your question is that you want to find the *first* occurrence of `(` from the *reversed* string.

```
SELECT
    LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(col)) + 1
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

In the above demo, the char index of the final `(` in the string `John(Jk)` correctly is determined to be 5.

Comment: Hi Tim Biegeleisen . Can i know why are you using the len-charindex, we can directly use the charindex('(',reverse('jack(crew))) right?

Comment: @AravindhanR If you want the char index as measured from the _start_ of the string, then obviously if you use`CHARINDEX` on the reversed string then the result will (generally) be wrong.  My answer converts back to an index of the original string.

Comment: Reverse is not working in teradata. what we can use instead of reverse

Comment: _Teradata_??? You tagged with SQL Server.  Changing your database now may draw downvotes.

Comment: I think that most of the query are same that's why i have tag in sql

Comment: You should close out this question and ask a new one for Teradata.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162724/discussion-between-aravindhan-r-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 0):

Use `charindex()` with `reverse()` function to find the index from the end

```
select charindex('(', reverse(data)) from table
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql).

Syntax:

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

Best Regarads!

Comment: How do you know where to start searching from the beginning?  How does this help the OP?

Comment: I am not intending to spoon-feed anyone here, so i linked a page where you can simply read everything you need to know about Charindex(). Remember that we are not here to solve his homework.